# Simulate effect of select() and poll() in kernel socket programming

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, kernel, system-calls

One of the Linux kernel drivers I am developing is using network communication in the kernel (`sock_create()`, `sock->ops->bind()`, and so on).

The problem is there will be multiple sockets to receive data from.  So I need something that will simulate a `select()` or `poll()` in kernel space.  Since these functions use file descriptors, I cannot use the system calls unless I use the system calls to create the sockets, but that seems unnecessary since I am working in the kernel.

So I was thinking of wrapping the default `sock->sk_data_ready` handler in my own handler (`custom_sk_data_ready()`), which would unlock a semaphore.  Then I can write my own `kernel_select()` function that tries to lock the semaphore and does a blocking wait until it is open.  That way the kernel function goes to sleep until the semaphore is unlocked by `custom_sk_data_ready()`.  Once `kernel_select()` gets the lock, it unlocks and calls `custom_sk_data_ready()` to relock it.  So the only additional initialization is to run `custom_sk_data_ready()` before binding a socket so the first call to `custom_select()` does not falsely trigger.

I see one possible problem.  If multiple receives occur, then multiple calls to `custom_sk_data_ready()` will try unlock the semaphore.  So to not lose the multiple calls and to track the `sock` being used, there will have to be a table or list of pointers to the sockets being used.  And `custom_sk_data_ready()` will have to flag in the table/list which socket it was passed.

Is this method sound?  Or should I just struggle with the user/kernel space issue when using the standard system calls?

**Initial Finding:**

All callback functions in the `sock` structure are called in an interrupt context.  This means they cannot sleep.  To allow the main kernel thread to sleep on a list of ready sockets, mutexes are used, but the `custom_sk_data_ready()` must act like a spinlock on the mutexes (calling `mutex_trylock()` repeatedly).  This also means that any dynamic allocation must use the `GFP_ATOMIC` flag.

---

Additional possibility:

For every open socket, replace each socket's `sk_data_ready()` with a custom one (`custom_sk_data_ready()`) and create a worker (`struct work_struct`) and work queue (`struct workqueue_struct`).  A common `process_msg()` function will be use for each worker.  Create a kernel module-level global list where each list element has a pointer to the socket and contains the worker structure.  When data is ready on a socket, `custom_sk_data_ready()` will execute and find the matching list element with the same socket, and then call `queue_work()` with the list element's work queue and worker.  Then the `process_msg()` function will be called, and can either find the matching list element through the contents of the `struct work_struct *` parameter (an address), or use the `container_of()` macro to get the address of the list structure that holds the worker structure.

Which technique is the most sound?

Comment: Can't you have a user-space helper program doing the `poll` ? Multiplexing input with `poll` or `select` is related to the scheduler (since the pausing process is idle, so other processes can run) so I won't do that inside the kernel!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: That is why I am only trying to simulate the sleep blocking of `poll()` and `select()`. Using those two system calls from the kernel is a last resort. I do suspect that there are problems with running `poll()` and `select()` in a user space helper. The helper must have access to a file descriptor (which is not done in `sock_create()`) and possibly permission to access a socket residing in kernel space. So now socket creation has to occur in the user space helper and the module must find the socket based on the user space file descriptor. Now it become more complicated.

Comment: You should not be doing any of that in the kernel.

Comment: @mpe, you are definitely wrong about the in kernel sockets.  They are used in the kernel.  And about messing with the sk_data_ready handler, that is also a common practice--particularly with modules that use Netlink.  The blocking/sleeping on the is another issue.  I did not see any examples of such behavior.

Comment: You **can** do it in the kernel, but that doesn't mean you **should**. Code should only be in the kernel if there's a really good reason it can't be in userspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second idea sounds more like it will work.

The CEPH code looks like it does something similar, see `net/ceph/messenger.c`.