# Alternatives for select and poll in linux kernel

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am having two socketsA socketB in the kernel modules listening to two different ports. I have a single thread which monitors the two sockets. Since it is in the kernel space, I am unable to use `select()`, `poll()`.

Is there a way i could get around this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using select()/poll() in device driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249514/using-select-poll-in-device-driver)

Comment: Tsyvarev.Your tip helped me in bringing the pieces together.And it worked for me